# Anyone has idea, what editor it this?

Tags: linux, terminal, editor

I've fount this screen on github and I fell in love with it :P
Here is the screen: [image]

Thanks a lot,
~JTK

Answer (score 1):

The window manager is [Dynamic Window Manager](https://github.com/l3pp4rd/dwm).

The editor in the left virtual terminal looks like [Vim](http://www.vim.org/) to me.

And the tool in the right virtual terminal is [Archey](https://github.com/djmelik/archey)